# Filling Colors for Some Countries in Carto

Tags: postgresql, carto, cartocss

I imported the "world borders" from the data set library in Carto. I want to fill/highlight some countries (say United States, Africa and Europe) with the same color but not all countries. How can I do this? Is there a way to select and filter the countries?

It is not necessary to do in Carto. If anyone has other tools to do it, I would like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Filters` or the `SQL` command line. Using the former options would give you more flexibility. For instance, if you want to select European countries you should type something like this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
 world_borders
WHERE
  region = 150
```

[image]

According to the `world_borders` dataset metadata, `150` is the code for Europe, `0` for Antartica, `142` for Asian countries, `19` for America, `2` for African countries, and `9` for Australia.

On the other hand, if you want to select just certain countries. This should be your SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  world_borders 
WHERE 
  name = 'Spain'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. So do you mean that actually I can just type the name of the cities/ countries in SQL query?

Comment: And if I want to choose several countries do I just type "AND"?

Comment: The name of the **countries** is stored in the `name` column of the `world_borders` dataset. But this dataset does not contain **cities**. For that, you have to look for the `populated_places` dataset.

Comment: You can use a range instead of `AND`. For example, `SELECT * FROM world_borders where name in ('Spain', 'Portugal', 'France')`. If you think I have solved your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry just 1 last question, if I want to select Spain in orange color, and all other countries in yellow colors, do you know how to do it? Thank you for such a great help!

Comment: The easiest way to do it is first clicking on "Simple" on the Wizards (and setting the color to yellow). Then go to the CartoCSS tab, and add the following code **at the end**: `[name="Spain"]{polygon-fill: orange; }`.